# Best approximation of a function among closed linear manifolds

Tags: analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal, projection, schauder-basis

Let $H$ be an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space and consider a $n-dimensional$ closed linear manifold generated by a subset of orthonormal basis, say, $M = span(\{u_1,u_2,\cdots,u_n\})$. Of course, there are possibly infinite $M$.

The Hilbert projection theorem tells us the best approximation of a function $u$ in $H$ which is closest to a $\textbf{given(fixed)}$ $M$. Thus, the best approximation depends on $M$.

I want to fix the dimension of a linear manifold we consider, but not the manifold itself. Among the possible $n-$dimensional linear closed manifolds, what is the best approximation?

Can we answer this question?

Comment: Could u pleas specify what function you meant, do u want  approximation of  noisy function?

Answer (score 0):

That is not what the Hilbert Projection theorem states. It states that in a Hilbert space $H$, given any point $p$ and any closed convex subset $S$, there is a unique best approximation $p' \in S$. More precisely, $p'$ is the unique point in $S$ which satisfies the following relation:

\begin{equation}
\|p-p'\| = \inf_{y \in S}\|p-y\|
\end{equation}

I'm not quite sure what you're referring to.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, what you wrote is what I said above. In your post, $y$ implies the best approximation of $p$ in the $S$. Among different subsets, what subset makes the projection is the best approximation. For example, If we choose another closed convex subset $S'$, then there exists $y'\in S'$. $y$ and $y'$ are different. So, if we have
$$
\|p-y\| \leq \|p-y'\| ,
$$
I want to say $S$ is better than $S'$. and I want to find the best $S^*$ among possible subsets.

Comment: The point $p$ itself spans a one-dimensional subspace S. Then the best approximation of $p$ in $S$ is just $p$ itself.

Comment: I said that subsets we consider has a fixed dimension $n$.

Comment: Fine, you can extend $p$ to a linearly independent set with $n$ elements. Now look at it's span.

Comment: Perhaps the question is unclear: is the following what was intended?  Let $u_1, u_2, \cdots $ be an orthonormal basis for the Hilbert space $H$ and let $u \in H$.  Let $n > 0$ be an integer.  What choice $\alpha_1, \cdots, \alpha_n \in \mathbb C $ and natural numbers $k_1, \cdots, k_n$ minimizes $ || \alpha_1u_{k_1} +\cdots+  \alpha_n u_{k_n} - u || $.